# How to merge/call the results of 2 callback function into a new function javascript?

Tags: javascript

What I currently have is 2 functions with callbacks.

At the end of validateEvent, there will be 2 variables `isDeactivated` and `eventOrganizer`.

While at the end of validateCheckIn, there will be 1 variable which is `isCheckIn`.

What I want to achieve now is merging the results of the 2 functions **validateEvent** and **validateCheckIn** into 1 new function where I can interact with 3 of the variables `isDeactivated`, `eventOrganizer` and `isCheckIn` in it.

What I've found so far is something like this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

But what if I wanted to add extra code in the newly merged function?

```
var isDeactivated = false;
var eventOrganizer;
var isCheckIn = false;

             function validateEvent(result) {
                $.post(
                    "**displayEventAPI**", 
                    { 
                        id: eventID,
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        result(
                            data["eventList"][0]["event_status"], 
                            data["eventList"][0]["event_creator"]
                        );
                    }
                )
            }

            validateEvent(function(event_status, event_creator) {
                if (event_status == 0) {
                    isDeactivated = true;
                }

                eventOrganizer = event_creator;

                console.log(isDeactivated, '--isDeactivated');
                console.log(eventOrganizer, '--eventOrganizer');
            });

            function validateCheckIn(result) {
                $.post(
                    "**displayAttendanceAPI", 
                    { 
                        event_id: eventID,
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.attendanceList.length; i++) {
                            if (data.attendanceList[i].badge_id === badgeID) {
                                isCheckIn = true;
                            }
                        }
                        result(
                            isCheckIn
                        );
                    }
                )
            }

            validateCheckIn(function(isCheckIn) {
                console.log(isCheckIn, '--isCheckIn');
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) functions for the implementation.

Also wrap your `async` function calling inside an another `async` function. Because `await` keyword can only be used inside an `async` function.

```
var isDeactivated = false;
var eventOrganizer;
var isCheckIn = false;

async function validateEvent() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.post(
      "**displayEventAPI**",
      {
        id: eventID,
      }).done(function (data) {
        resolve({
          event_status: data["eventList"][0]["event_status"],
          event_creator: data["eventList"][0]["event_creator"]
        });
      }
      )
  })
}

async function validateCheckIn(result) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.post("**displayAttendanceAPI", {
        event_id: eventID,
      }).done(function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.attendanceList.length; i++) {
          if (data.attendanceList[i].badge_id === badgeID) {
            isCheckIn = true;
          }
        }
        resolve(isCheckIn);
      })
  })
}

function thirdFunction(event_status, event_creator, isCheckIn) {
  console.log(event_status, '--isCheckIn');
  console.log(event_creator, '--isCheckIn');
  console.log(isCheckIn, '--isCheckIn');
}

async function execute() {
  const { event_status, event_creator } = await validateEvent();
  const isCheckIn = await validateCheckIn();
  thirdFunction(event_status, event_creator, isCheckIn);
}

execute();
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I get this error: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: @Lance wrap your `async` function calling inside an another `async` function. Because `await` keyword can only be used inside an `async` function. I have updated my answer.